# Test Class isn't Picked Up In Maven

Tags: junit, spring-test

I have a test class in a Spring Boot (v 2.45) project.

```
@RunWith(OrderedTestRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MyResourceIT {...}
```

I can run it in Idea, but

```
mvn test
```

won't run it for some reason.

The test class uses JUnit 4 and Spring Boot v2.xx uses Junit 5. I don't know whether that is a reason or not. The followings are the import statements of the test class:

```
import com.hackerrank.test.utility.Order;
import com.hackerrank.test.utility.OrderedTestRunner;
import com.hackerrank.test.utility.ResultMatcher;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringClassRule;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringMethodRule;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
```

and I add the following two test related dependencies to the pom.xml file:

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>com.hackerrank.applications</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit-ordered-test-runner</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offical document says that

> If you have tests that use JUnit 4, JUnit 5’s vintage engine can be used to run them. To use the vintage engine, add a dependency on junit-vintage-engine, as shown in the following example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```